# Create an instance of a class known at runtime

Tags: iphone, ios, class, runtime, instantiation

I have this code but it returns "nil" instead of a new class.
Here it is useless but in my programme it makes sens.

```
    Class myClass = [SettingsTableViewController class];  

    UIViewController *targetViewController = [[myClass alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: if your class doesn't have a nib it will not work when you push on navigation controller.

Comment: yes it does, the view is described programmatically. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting something or you might don't know. Here is the proper code.

```
Class myClass = NSCLassFromString(@"yourClassName");

if(myClass){
   myClass = [[yourclassName alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: The problem was elsewhere, with a early "nil" in an NSDictionnary. The code I posted is working.